# Trying to implement AWS cognito Authentication in angular 13

Tags: angular13

Trying to implement AWS cognito Authentication in angular 13
(alias) const Amplify: AmplifyClass
import Amplify
'default' is deprecated.ts(6385)
index.d.ts(18, 4): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
can you suggest what needs to be done or any other simple methods to integrate.

Answer (score 13):

Switch from the default import to a named import:

`import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";`

instead of

`import Amplify from "aws-amplify";`